# Maven assembly: copy from specific sub-folder of dependency

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin

I'm using Maven assembly plugin to build a WAR of our product (previously done by Ant). As there're many leftovers of Apache Ant, there's one specific requirement that would make build process easier: copy specific sub-folder of dependency (e.g., jar or war resource) to a specific target sub-folder.

So far I learned that Assembly descriptors allow to specify `<outputDirectory>`, but is there's any chance to specify a `<sourceDirectory>`? E.g., I want to apply this rule for one single WAR or JAR type dependency.

Consider this example of assembly descriptor fragment (not 100% accurate):

```xml
    <dependencySet>
        <unpack>true</unpack>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <useProjectArtifact>false</useProjectArtifact>
        <includes>
            <include>my-specific-dependency:war</include>
        </includes>
        <outputDirectory>WEB-INF/myresources</outputDirectory>
    </dependencySet>
```

I want to say that I want to copy some folder from my-specific-dependency:war to WEB-INF/myresources.

**EDIT** NB: I'm aware that this is not a very correct requirement as we shouldn't know what's inside an artifact, the correct way would be declaring to extract the whole artifact to the target directory (neat declarative approach).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use the Maven Dependency plugin to do this, with the *unpack* goal:
http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/unpack-mojo.html

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>unpack-database-scripts</id>
      <phase>compile</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>unpack</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
          <artifactItems>
           <artifactItem>
             <groupId>myGroup</groupId>
             <artifactId>myArtifact</artifactId>
             <version>1.0</version>
             <type>war</type>
             <overWrite>true</overWrite>
             <includes>...</includes>
             <outputDirectory>…</outputDirectory>
           </artifactItem>
         </artifactItems>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Thanks, your comment helped a lot. Now I hope to change the way I build the final WAR using maven-war-plugin and maven-dependency-plugin. Can I have multiple <artifactItem> elements referencing to the same arifact, but having different <includes> and <outputDirectory> ?

Comment: You can give that a try, I guess. If that doesn't work, you can still use multiple *executions*.

Comment: To be honest, the answer provided by me provides a direct answer to original question. But you clearly showed how to achieve my target with a simple and correct solution.

Answer (score 2):

First i recomment that you check the [maven-war-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/) to do that job instead with [maven-assembly-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/). Furthermore check the [documentation](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly.html) about the dependencySet which contains such options for unpacking etc. Change your packaging of the module to war and make it fit to the maven conventions and don't use Maven as ant...which currently looks like it.

Comment: You are probably right I should try maven-war-plugin, which I will. With combination of suggestions proposed by @nwinkler, I hope I can achieve the same flexibility, as I expected to achieve by using assembly plugin.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that assembly descriptor (since ver. 2.2-beta-1) provides [unpackOptions](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly.html#class_unpackOptions) instructions, including `<dependencySet>`. Exactly what I needed.